# In short i accidentally typed sudo rm /* and now my system doesnt boot as something is deleted in /

Tags: boot, kernel, data-recovery, rm

I am a beginner and hence did a child's mistake and now i cant enter my system and when I try to enter recovery shell it says "Kernel panic - not syncing attempted to kill init?" and i didn't find any answer on how to solve my error online . I am desperate ...

Comment: Reinstall the system and reload your backups.

Comment: Install anew. I hope you have a backup from your personal data.

Comment: i have installed many things and everything is intact but the symlinks and some other files were lost but i dont know how to add those symlinks that were deleted through live USB . The issue is that i cant enter my system but every program,every file exists . i didnt use "sudo rm -r /*" i just did sudo rm /* so no folders containing files were deleted

Comment: Most of us have done things like this. We all learn from our mistakes. It is a very good idea to set up a backup routine ;-)

Comment: i have installed many things and everything is intact but the symlinks and some other files were lost but i dont know how to add those symlinks that were deleted through live USB . The issue is that i cant enter my system but every program,every file exists . i didnt use "sudo rm -r /*" i just did sudo rm /* so no folders containing files were deleted

Comment: The links, sbin, bin, lib, lib64, lib32, libx32 all go to /usr/<same name>. Just replace them.  e.g. sudo ln -s /usr/bin /bin

Comment: We understand that you didn't run the recursive flag. What you did is still fatal and requires a reinstall.

Comment: Addition to what is told above: reinstall WITHOUT formatting. That will leave all personal configuration as is.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Undo sudo rm -R /\*](https://askubuntu.com/questions/555550/undo-sudo-rm-r)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can save your personal files (to another drive), if you have enough drive space, save the whole file tree `/home` preserving the ownership and permissions.

- Simple example, boot from another system, for example a live system in a USB drive, mount the partition of your broken installed system to a mountpoint and backup to a tarball,

  ```
  cd /mountpoint
  sudo tar -cvf /path/home-backup.tar home
  ```
- Maybe make a compressed tarball (slower, but needs less drive space),

  ```
  cd /mountpoint
  sudo tar -cvJf /path/home-backup.tar.xz home
  ```

Then you can re-install and later on restore your settings and personal files from the [compressed] tarball.

You can restore by

- Change directory to `/`

  ```
  cd /
  ```
- Run the following command to extract everything from the tarball,

  ```
  sudo tar -xvf /path/home-backup.tar
  ```

  or

  ```
  sudo tar -xvf /path/home-backup.tar.xz
  ```

Answer (score 0):

ooooh im sorry to say hear this well better than trying to fix something u have no idea where to begin u can use

bootable usb stick to recover ur files then reinstall mostly wont be necessary unless u installed the entire system in /

also next time create partions if u havent already

```
/
/boot
/var
/home
```

so that so can reinstall and change only specific partions during installation

or use system recovery image to do the same from the bootloader

will have to probably reinstall also keep backups

Instead of using

```sh
rm -rf * postfix.txt # accidental space between
```

would delete all  files

The file name used within quotes is considered as a single file
this will avoid errors like what u did

```sh
rm -rf '* postfix.txt'
```

on the other hand
wont delete bc file by the name `*\ postfix.txt` doesnt exist

better to use `find` command

```sh
find . -name "* foldername/" -type d -exec rm -rf {} \;

or 

find . -name "/foldername/ *" -type d | xargs -0 rm -r
```

Here,

```
-name = name of file

  -type = f for file , d for directory

  -exec = to execute commands followed {contains the output from search} \;slash is for closing 


   | = (pipe operator) used to join two commands like joining a pipe

   xargs = is used to execute commands
```