# accidentally did `sudo rm -r /*`, can I fix it?

Tags: ssh, sudo, amazon-ec2, aws, rm

I accidentally did `sudo rm -r /*` from a directory. I don't know what  got deleted. Now I can no longer login to my instance via ssh. Is there a way to recover the instance or creating new one is the only choice?

Answer (score 1):

As elaborated in [in this question](https://askubuntu.com/q/555550/51957), the command you issued was *fatal* beyond recovery.

You most likely have to use your backup to restore your system.
If you don't have a backup ( :-((( ), you can attempt a *live recovery* as long as your services are running (in memory), meaning that you extract as much data as possible from remote at the service level.

Comment: I got it, thanks!